# Загадка с функцией или как я угадывал нужную функцию MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. 
При выполнении лабы, касающейся строчных функций столкнулся с интерестным заданием.
Есть пример:

```
SELECT COUNT(passport_series) WHERE POSITION('0301' IN 'passport_series') > 0 FROM students;
```

Суть задания состоит в том,чтобы подсчитать кол - во студентов, серия паспорта которых равна "0301". У меня код вызвал сомнения. Ведь функция "POSITION" возвращает номер символа (вхождения) его в строку, ну или номер вхождения подстроки в строку, ведь так?
Спросил у препода, а он говорит мол, все правильно. Естественно выбивает ошибку - другого и не ждал. Вопрос в том, как можно подсчитать кол - во студентов с данной серией паспорта, с помощью какой - нибудь строчной функции, и вообще естьли такая?
Спасибо.

Comment: А какая ошибка у вас возникает?

Comment: Думаю, что вам надо убрать кавычки у passport_series.  WHERE POSITION('0301' IN passport_series) > 0

Comment: @MuscledBoy, почему не `WHERE passport_series = '0301'`?

Comment: @Mike, в серии всего 4 цифры.

Comment: ВИдите в чем проблема я вывел информацию об серии и она у меня 301, хотя вводил 0301. Поле имеет тип VARCHAR. Сообственно вчера, как сказал Mike, в другой теме мне это и предложили. Видимо по - этому и не находит таких студентов????

Comment: @Mike, вовсе не в одном поле. Просто тема такая с примерами и надо повторить с собственным вариантом.

Comment: @Visman, а если  **SELECT COUNT(passport_series) FROM students WHERE passport_series IN ('0301'); или только так, как у Вас?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, все равно спасибо за Ваше внимание

Comment: А почему у вас в поле село 301, этого быть не может если вы правильно вставляли (модифицировали) запись, заключая строковое значение '0301' в кавычки. Такое могло произойти только если вы написали `update/insert set series=0301` т.е. без кавычек. Если в БД корректные данные - то искать обычным равенством `where series='0301'`

Comment: Наверно здесь и кроется ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе код из примера был правильным за исключением момента с FROM (он ставится после COUNT) и знак ">", видимо, не оттуда скопирован:

```
SELECT COUNT(passport_series) FROM students WHERE POSITION('0301' IN passport_series);
```

Основная ошибкабыла при вводеданных: как ответили выше, серии вводятся посредством **''** .

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` можно использовать по синтаксису только после `FROM`.

Comment: учти это в след. раз

Comment: спасибо за внимание